# Finding unique pairs in the table ordered by time

Tags: mysql, sql

The following snapshot, represents conversations between different users. I am trying to get the last conversation between each user. For example, last conversation between 1 and 16, 1 and 17 and so on. So, 1 and 16 will be same as 16 and 1.
[image]

I wrote the following query:

```
select distinct senderId, receiveId, messageId, message from messages 
  where senderId in (1,16) order by sentTime
```

This tells me the latest conversation between 1 and 16, but none of the senderId is known before. How could I then find these results?

Comment: Can you clarify the desired output?  Perhaps a sample of expected output?

Comment: @MarkJ.Bobak I am looking find all the last conversation between users. Like last conversation between 1 and 16, last between 1 and 17 and so on

Comment: I see every day people that needs SQL window functions but chose a database without this feature.

Comment: If time isn't in a consistent format, this is going to be insanely difficult

Comment: @danihp it's not such a big deal; there's usually a workaround. Besides, the latest version (beta) has window functions

Comment: Why a vote down??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group by`.  This is particularly easy if the message ids are increasing along with the time (which I assume is true):

```
select least(senderId, receiverId) as id1,
       greatest(senderId, receiverId) as id2,
       max(messageId), max(sentTime)
from messages
group by id1, id2;
```

If you want other information, such as the message text, just use this as a subquery and join in the additional information.